# Wait for class name to be empty - Selenium Webdriver - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

With the following code, the class for the current screen that's dislayed will ="active".

In the case below, the Payment History screen is currently shown (a ui-sref="paymenthistory")

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-layout-sidebar nav-stacked">

<li class="" ui-sref-active="active">
<a ui-sref="paymentmethods" href="#/user/payment-methods">
</li>

<li class="active" ui-sref-active="active">
<a ui-sref="paymenthistory" href="#/my-account/payment-history">
</li>

<li ui-sref-active="active" class="">
<a ui-sref="password" href="#/user/change-password">
</li>

</ul>
```

I'm trying to wait for a specific page to be loaded, however, I'm not sure how to specify the screen.

The following obviously doesn't work because there is always an li class that equals active.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li[class='active']")));
```

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to say, wait for the paymentmethods screen to be active

Comment: I'm assuming the URI of the page changes when you navigate to Payment History? Why not just use that?

Comment: I could have used the URI for this particular instance, however, I was going for the logic @alecxe provided as it will help me out in other areas that are not determined by the URI. I do appreciate your input, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out how to say, wait for the paymentmethods screen to be active

Then, ask for two conditions to be true at the same time:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li.active > a[ui-sref=paymentmethods]")));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. I just had to modify the syntax by adding the ' ' around paymentmethods.